# Can't reboot, shut down or sleep ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: boot, dual-boot, suspend, lenovo, shutdown

I've seen this problem asked several times, but none of the solutions works for me, I have a Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 15IAH7, and I installed Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows 11, this OS works perfectly, but when I use Ubuntu and I try to shut down or reboot, the Lenovo screen appears and that's it, I can't wake it up, I can do anything, The only thing I'm able to do is to force the shut down same thing happens when tried to just suspend the laptop.

I deactivated the secure boot because I saw sometimes secure boot can bring some problems with Ubuntu, I tried to use an older kernel version as well, I tried to run the solution in this thread  askubuntu.com/q/1480075, I tried to remove Ubuntu and install it again but still, nothing works.

I would appreciate some help to make Ubuntu work perfectly (I'm kind of new with Ubuntu)